# How do I use node redis inside a nextjs api in the same way I use mongoDB?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, redis, next.js

I'm trying to use Redis in a nextJs API which has a custom express server. I created a util file for Redis in order to connect to the Redis labs, the same way I did with mongodb. The problem is that when I try to use the `client.Hset` the console keeps sending me errors that `econ refused`, but I also made sure that when Redis is connected it console logs a string. So the console, logs both the error of `econ refused`, and the log `connected to redis`. This is how my util file looks like:

```
/* ------ connecting to redis ------ */
const redis = require('redis');
const { promisify } = require('util');
const client = redis.createClient({
    host: process.env.REDIS_HOSTNAME,
    port: process.env.REDIS_PORT,
    password: process.env.REDIS_PASSWORD
});
client.on('connect', ()=>{
  console.log('connected to redis')
})
/* promisifying redis in order to use async functionality */
const redisHget = promisify(client.hget).bind(client)
const redisHset = promisify(client.hset).bind(client)

module.export = {redisHget, redisHset}
```

It seems like every time I call the API, it reconnects to Redis. may I know if there is a way I can use redis the same way I use MongoDB by just creating and importing collections so that it doesn't keep reconnecting to the redis labs server?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Lee Robinson (DevRel @ Vercel), wrote a nice article about using Redis in Next.js. https://leerob.io/blog/serverless-redis-nextjs.

Complete Example here: https://github.com/vercel/next.js/blob/canary/examples/with-redis/README.md

Snippets:

```sh
# env.local
REDIS_URL=redis://:password@endpoint:port
```

We'll use [ioredis](https://github.com/luin/ioredis), a Node.js Redis client with async/await support, to connect to Redis.

```js
// lib/redis.js
import Redis from 'ioredis';

const redis = new Redis(process.env.REDIS_URL);

export default redis;
```

Using it, either in `pages/` or `pages/api/`,

```js
import redis from '@/lib/redis';

const value = JSON.parse(await redis.hget('feedback', id));
```